Github action running out of space
My Github action recently started running out of space. Unfortunately, I'm running in a Docker container so I'm not sure what my options are to reach back to the Host and delete unnecessary tools.
name: MyBuild
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  workflow_call:

jobs:
  compile:
    name: Run Sonarqube
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: my_image:latest
    steps:
    - name: Free 
           //delete stuff on the host here
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:

All of the tricks I've seen require me to be able to run a command on the host before the container starts.

If you use GitHub Team or GitHub Enterprise Cloud plans you can use larger runners. They offer

More RAM, CPU, and disk space
Static IP addresses
The ability to group runners
Autoscaling to support concurrent workflows



thanks, unfortunately I'm unable to bump those up.
